# Difference between regular and performance profiler mode in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug JS ([propellerjs](https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Propeller)) animation in Angular 7 app which runs on requestAnimationFrame but runs very slow.

The problem is - I'm unable to reproduce the issue while trying to record performance profile - the app just works fine in there.

What is the difference between regular mode and performance profile recording mode? I tried to turn off all extensions and restart the browser, but that didnt help.

you can notice the wheel rotates very slow in regular mode and rotates nice and fast while I'm trying to record it with profiler.

I expected to see performance issues in profiler, but it just works fine when I'm trying to record.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three modes relevant to the questions:

1. DevTools are closed
2. DevTools are open, not performance recording
3. DevTools are open and performance recording is running.

Mode #2 is expected to be slower than #1 as DevTools add quite a bunch of hooks into the running page for debugging purposes.

However, when you run the profiler (mode #3) most of the hooks are temporarily disabled.

That results in the mode #1 should be the fastest, #3 is bit slower (due to profiling), and #2 is the slowest.

In the screencast I can see that you're comparing #2 vs #3. That's expected the #3 is faster.

Comment: P.S. alph is a DevTools engineer.

Comment: @alph tyvm for detailed answer, pretty straightforward!

Comment: Oh my... This issue has been bugging me every now and then, and never knew how to google for it. Now I have finally found your answer. I never realized how much slower things were with devtools open!

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and this turned out to be the answer. Just having the devtools open to the Console tab was a 2x slowdown, in some purely-computational code running in a worker thread, even with no breakpoints or similar thing set. This performance impact was really surprising.